# Increase x and y when requestanimationframe is called

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want the x and y to increase by 1 in each requestAnimationFrame, it only increases once

https://jsfiddle.net/2mzb7axu/1/

```
update(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
    this.x++
    this.y++
    ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `animate` function is initiating the `Line` constructor with every `update` call.
Try initiating the `Line` class on the `Display` constructor, something like this:

```
constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.canvas.width = this.width;
    this.canvas.height = this.height;
    this.animateBound = this.animate.bind(this);

    this.line = new Line();
}
```

and within your `update` function, call the existing `Line`'s instance:

```
animate() {
    this.line.update(this.ctx);
    console.log('Animate called');
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animateBound);
}
```